# Best way to draw information from .txt-file

Tags: c++, regex, text, benchmarking

I am currently benchmarking some C++-code. The benchmark-tool sadly only prints a string to the terminal(i have to use this benchmark-tool, so please no recommendations for new ones).

A line from it looks like this:

```
name, time,     cycle,     instr, L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,     task, scale,  IPC,  CPU,  GHz 
Blitz2D, 0.00, 198423.00, 439478.00,  615.00,     3.00,  958.00, 39157.00,     1, 2.21, 1.14, 5.07
```

What i am doing now, is this: `./a.out > some.txt`.

Every new test has its own new line, and every independent testing block(basically the same test but with altered testing parameters) is separated by a special-char of my choice.

What would be the best way to get certain information out of this file? 
Best would probably be, some sort of array with every number in the second row as one index...

How would i do this? Keep in mind, that i have literally no idea about python, bash, regex, etc. (i am open for suggestions and will try to learn the recommended stuff, but i don't want to have to learn multiple to find out what works best ...)

EDIT:
In the End, i need this information in graphical plots of different kinds ... so any format best suited for that would be perfect

Here is a complete testing block:

```
§
Testing with MxK * KxM Matrices - M: 29 - K: 67
    name, time,    cycle,     instr, L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,     task, scale,  IPC,  CPU,  GHz 
Fastor2D, 0.00, 77568.00, 140312.00,  780.00,   206.00,  161.00, 15781.00,     1, 1.81, 1.45, 4.92 
    name, time,    cycle,     instr, L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,     task, scale,  IPC,  CPU,  GHz 
Fastor2D, 0.00, 76681.00, 140312.00,  802.00,    39.00,  130.00, 15571.00,     1, 1.83, 1.44, 4.92 
    name, time,    cycle,     instr, L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,     task, scale,  IPC,  CPU,  GHz 
Fastor2D, 0.00, 77174.00, 140312.00,  788.00,    31.00,  135.00, 15718.00,     1, 1.82, 1.45, 4.91 
    name, time,    cycle,     instr, L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,     task, scale,  IPC,  CPU,  GHz 
Fastor2D, 0.00, 76720.00, 140312.00,  781.00,    30.00,  134.00, 15616.00,     1, 1.83, 1.44, 4.91 
    name, time,    cycle,     instr, L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,     task, scale,  IPC,  CPU,  GHz 
Fastor2D, 0.00, 77052.00, 140312.00,  781.00,    16.00,  127.00, 15526.00,     1, 1.82, 1.43, 4.96 

   name, time,      cycle,      instr,   L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,      task, scale,  IPC,  CPU,  GHz 
Eigen2D, 0.00, 3507208.00, 2477793.00, 129053.00,   999.00,  898.00, 724590.00,     1, 0.71, 1.01, 4.84 
   name, time,      cycle,      instr,   L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,      task, scale,  IPC,  CPU,  GHz 
Eigen2D, 0.00, 3554544.00, 2477793.00, 128932.00,    37.00,  787.00, 734337.00,     1, 0.70, 1.01, 4.84 
   name, time,      cycle,      instr,   L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,      task, scale,  IPC,  CPU,  GHz 
Eigen2D, 0.00, 3517898.00, 2477793.00, 128931.00,    25.00,  734.00, 726840.00,     1, 0.70, 1.01, 4.84 
   name, time,      cycle,      instr,   L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,      task, scale,  IPC,  CPU,  GHz 
Eigen2D, 0.00, 3537674.00, 2483174.00, 129548.00,   683.00,  761.00, 730925.00,     1, 0.70, 1.01, 4.84 
   name, time,      cycle,      instr,   L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,      task, scale,  IPC,  CPU,  GHz 
Eigen2D, 0.00, 3527303.00, 2481152.00, 129326.00,   190.00,  741.00, 728567.00,     1, 0.70, 1.01, 4.84 

     name, time,    cycle,    instr, L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,     task, scale,  IPC,  CPU,  GHz 
XTensor2D, 0.00, 60718.00, 78733.00, 3363.00,   434.00,  206.00, 12772.00,     1, 1.30, 1.72, 4.75 
     name, time,    cycle,    instr, L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,     task, scale,  IPC,  CPU,  GHz 
XTensor2D, 0.00, 56300.00, 78733.00, 3335.00,    32.00,  146.00, 11445.00,     1, 1.40, 1.79, 4.92 
     name, time,    cycle,    instr, L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,     task, scale,  IPC,  CPU,  GHz 
XTensor2D, 0.00, 55279.00, 78733.00, 3340.00,    39.00,  121.00, 11305.00,     1, 1.42, 1.79, 4.89 
     name, time,    cycle,    instr, L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,     task, scale,  IPC,  CPU,  GHz 
XTensor2D, 0.00, 55294.00, 78733.00, 3344.00,    22.00,  114.00, 11297.00,     1, 1.42, 1.79, 4.89 
     name, time,    cycle,    instr, L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,     task, scale,  IPC,  CPU,  GHz 
XTensor2D, 0.00, 54857.00, 78733.00, 3322.00,     6.00,  108.00, 11233.00,     1, 1.44, 1.80, 4.88 

   name, time,     cycle,     instr, L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,     task, scale,  IPC,  CPU,  GHz 
Blitz2D, 0.00, 198423.00, 439478.00,  615.00,     3.00,  958.00, 39157.00,     1, 2.21, 1.14, 5.07 
   name, time,     cycle,     instr, L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,     task, scale,  IPC,  CPU,  GHz 
Blitz2D, 0.00, 190556.00, 439478.00,  584.00,     2.00,  964.00, 39058.00,     1, 2.31, 1.14, 4.88 
   name, time,     cycle,     instr, L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,     task, scale,  IPC,  CPU,  GHz 
Blitz2D, 0.00, 190088.00, 439478.00,  581.00,     8.00,  948.00, 39057.00,     1, 2.31, 1.14, 4.87 
   name, time,     cycle,     instr, L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,     task, scale,  IPC,  CPU,  GHz 
Blitz2D, 0.00, 190177.00, 439478.00,  594.00,    11.00,  941.00, 38989.00,     1, 2.31, 1.14, 4.88 
   name, time,     cycle,     instr, L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,     task, scale,  IPC,  CPU,  GHz 
Blitz2D, 0.00, 190099.00, 439478.00,  584.00,     7.00,  943.00, 39030.00,     1, 2.31, 1.14, 4.87 

     name, time,    cycle,    instr, L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,    task, scale,  IPC,   CPU,  GHz 
FTensor2D, 0.00, 24970.00, 17695.00,   96.00,    19.00,  101.00, 4851.00,     1, 0.71, 29.76, 5.15 
     name, time,    cycle,    instr, L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,    task, scale,  IPC,   CPU,  GHz 
FTensor2D, 0.00, 24619.00, 17695.00,   85.00,     8.00,   94.00, 4738.00,     1, 0.72, 48.35, 5.20 
     name, time,    cycle,    instr, L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,    task, scale,  IPC,   CPU,  GHz 
FTensor2D, 0.00, 24471.00, 17695.00,   68.00,     2.00,   94.00, 4739.00,     1, 0.72, 48.36, 5.16 
     name, time,    cycle,    instr, L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,    task, scale,  IPC,   CPU,  GHz 
FTensor2D, 0.00, 24454.00, 17695.00,   74.00,     4.00,   93.00, 4727.00,     1, 0.72, 43.77, 5.17 
     name, time,    cycle,    instr, L1-miss, LLC-miss, br-miss,    task, scale,  IPC,   CPU,  GHz 
FTensor2D, 0.00, 24318.00, 17695.00,   83.00,    16.00,   93.00, 4703.00,     1, 0.73, 54.69, 5.17 
§
```

Comment: It really depends on what you want to do with that information... your output is in CSV format even though you write it to a text file. Excel/LibreOffice Calc could open this file into a spreadsheet with no problem. If you just want to print out a single column, bash tools could be good. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/285774/cut-column-2-from-text-file If you need to read the whole file in as a data array, python's numpy or pandas could be a good tool. 
Again, it depends on what you want to do with your data.

Comment: actually the LibreOffice idea does sound great, as i want to create graphical plots from the information. I'll look into it. Any recommandations and warnings upfront?

Comment: Not really. Use the import tool and make sure it separates your data properly... e.g. Don't use fixed width format when this is clearly comma separated.

Comment: With your new edit, using Calc, you'd have to delete the 'name, time, ... ' rows by hand each time you import it. Or, you could do some searching to remove them (such as using bash's string editor tool, sed). Its up to you on how to craft your work flow. Ideally you would script it. gnuplot would be a good tool for plotting if you don't want to use Calc, but it may be more hassle than it's worth to learn it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your edit, you could grep "2D" > data.txt to get only the data and then open that in Calc. 2D is in all of your name columns so it would be an easy string to use.

```
# run benchmarking
./a.out > some.txt
# Extract data from some.txt
grep "2D" some.txt > data.csv
# Open with libreoffice calc and plot
libreoffice data.csv
```

Alternatively you could use a command line graphing tool (say gnuplot) to plot data.txt You could also be more specific with the grep command to extract only specific data.

Comment: i'll try it, thank you very much, i'll write again when i get some results

Comment: It worked, but now i have to see how i can do the avg of every 5th line in LibreOffice